# Found GLEW when build cmake in CLion, but could not found GLEW when build in command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, opengl, cmake, clion

I've been working in this project on CLion, seems nothing strange happened at all. But I was trying to run it on VS Code, or I can say, I want to run it manually without any
IDE's help.

Here is my CMakeList.txt

```
# Find OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if (OpenGL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Debug: Found OpenGL")
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS OpenGL::GL)
else()
    message(STATUS "Debug: Could NOT find OpenGL")
endif ()
# Find GLEW
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Debug: Found GLEW")
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS GLEW::glew)
else()
    message(STATUS "Debug: Could NOT find GLEW")
endif ()
```

Build project in CLion, it run just fine

```sh
-- Debug: Found OpenGL
-- Debug: Found GLEW
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Debug: SUBDIRECTORY OpenGL::GL;GLEW::glew;glfw
-- Debug: MainWindow OpenGL::GL;GLEW::glew;glfw;SUBDIRECTORY
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Workplace/GameMaking/GLFW/GLFW-1st-project/cmake-build-debug
[ 72%] Built target glfw
[ 81%] Built target SUBDIRECTORY
[ 90%] Built target MainWindow
[100%] Built target My_Project

Build finished
```

But when I try to build it with command line in VS CODE, I create vs-build directory inside project folder just like CLion did (CLion create a folder called cmake-build-debug)

```sh
mkdir vs-build
cd vs-build
cmake ..
```

It cannot found GLEW

```sh
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
-- Debug: Found OpenGL
CMake Error at D:/Programs/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS GLEW_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Programs/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  D:/Programs/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:215 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Why would CLion can find my glew lib but my cmake manually cannot?

Did I make any mistakes in my cmake or used wrong cmake commands?

Comment: At a guess clion passes additional arguments or environment variables to cmake. Where have you installed glew? Have you passed that path to cmake?

Comment: Since you are using `find_package(... REQUIRED)` and not `QUIET`, there is no need to check the `_FOUND` variables or print any messages. There is also no need to accumulate into a variable; just call `target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE OpenGL::GL GLEW::glew)` directly. Simple is _always_ better when it comes to CMake.

Comment: You should compare the CMakeCache.txt files of both build directories (the working CLion one and the failing VSCode one) to see what is different.

Comment: Also it's very clear that is not your _full_ CMakeLists.txt. Please produce a [complete, minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AlexReinking I wanted to add multiple subdirectories, I add each lib to `EXTRA_LIBS` then use `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS})`

Comment: Don't do that. If you have a logical group of dependencies, link them to an `INTERFACE` library and link your targets to that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like @AlanBirtles is right, I had run some codes which might added GLEW path to my project build before at CLion, then I rechecked and thought that those are redundant lines so I deleted them. So now my cmake need to find package manually.

I've managed to find GLEW package manually like this

```
# Find GLEW 
find_package(GLEW QUIET)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Debug: Found GLEW")
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS GLEW::glew)
else()
    message(STATUS "Debug: Could NOT find package GLEW automatically")
    message(STATUS "Debug: Finding GLEW manually")
    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/Programs/glew")
    find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS GLEW::glew)
endif ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have glew installed to a custom location. This is fine and normal, but hard-coding absolute paths to your personal file system is **very bad practice**. Please do not make a habit of doing this.

You can hint to CMake where to find GLEW by setting `-DGLEW_ROOT=D:/Programs/glew` at the configure command line.

When searching for a dependency you should avoid doing *anything* beyond a simple `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)`. CMake already has a complex search procedure that is designed to be overridden by the build-system's users.

Every "convenient" behavior you hard code into your CMakeLists.txt will eventually become *annoying* instead. Keep this file to an **absolute minimum** and store your environment specific settings in CMakePresets.json

Comment: This is the command I used `cmake .. -DGLEW_ROOT=D:/Programs/glew -DGLFW_PATH=D:/Programs/glfw-master`
With `-DGLEW_ROOT` use to specific to **pakage** GLEW, and `-DGLFW_PATH` to link to GLFW folder which contains CMakeLists.txt to **build it along with project**, Is that alright?